# How to return the sequential number for each row like MYSQL ROW_NUMBER() in DolphinDB?

Tags: mysql, sql, dolphindb

I got a table as follows.

[image]

It is expected to be grouped by `area` values, and sorted in a descending order by `qyt` values. In addition, the ranking should be unique for duplicate qyt values. I want to get this result:

[image]

Any SQL statement to get this result?

Comment: https://www.dolphindb.com/help/FunctionsandCommands/FunctionReferences/r/rank.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following script：

```
tmp_t = select *,denseRank(qyt) as ranking from t context by area order by area ,ranking desc
```

select id,area,qyt,rowNo(ranking)+1 as ranking from tmp_t context by area